# ¿Como crear PK identity en DataTable temporal?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando en una app windows Forms, Visual Studio 2015.
El escenario es que tengo un DataGridView donde voy a ingresar items a un Detalle, Voy a ingresar datos de un producto de un rango de tallas que valen un precio, y el mismo producto voy a ingresarlo con otro rango de tallas que valen otro precio, entonces necesito ingresar el mismo producto mas de una vez.

Para esto tengo implementado un DataTable temporal muesto el código:

```
public class DetalleCompraRepository
{
    private DataTable _detalleTemp = new DataTable();
    public DetalleCompraRepository()
    {
        _detalleTemp = new DataTable("_detalleTemp");
        DataColumn colId = new DataColumn();
        colId.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        colId.AutoIncrement = true;
        colId.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        colId.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
        _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("colId", typeof(int));
        _detalleTemp.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { _detalleTemp.Columns[0] };

        _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("ProductoId", typeof(int));
        _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("Descripcion", typeof(string));
        _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("Cantidad", typeof(int));
        _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("Precio", typeof(decimal));
        _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("Importe", typeof(decimal), "(Precio * Cantidad)");
    }

    public DataTable PDetalleTemp
    {
        get { return _detalleTemp; }
    }

    public void Agregar(DetalleCompra entity)
    {
        var fila = _detalleTemp.Rows.Find(entity.DetalleCompraId);
        if (fila == null)
        {
            fila = _detalleTemp.NewRow();
            fila["colId"] = entity.DetalleCompraId;
            fila["ProductoId"] = entity.ProductoId;
            fila["Descripcion"] = entity.Descripcion;
            fila["Cantidad"] = entity.Cantidad;
            fila["Precio"] = entity.Precio;
            fila["Importe"] = entity.Total;
            _detalleTemp.Rows.Add((fila));
        }
    }
}
```

El DataTable me pide un pk, el cual se lo puse pero, no me permite ingresar el mismo id, entonces nesecito ponerle un pk identity para que me permita ingresar el mismo item.
Lo he intentado en esta porción de código:

```
DataColumn colId = new DataColumn();
        colId.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        colId.AutoIncrement = true;
        colId.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        colId.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
        _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("colId", typeof(int));
        _detalleTemp.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { _detalleTemp.Columns[0] };
```

Si puedo ingresar un primer item, pero cuando intento ingresar un segundo item, en el método Agregar ya no ingresa en la condicion `if (fila == null)` y eso indica que fila no esta null.

La manera que agrego los items es la siguiente:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var entity = new DetalleCompra()
        {
            ProductoId = Convert.ToInt32(txtProductoId.Text),
            Descripcion = txtDescripcion.Text,
            Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text),
            Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrecio.Text)
        };
        _detalleCompra.Agregar(entity);
        dgvDetalle.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvDetalle.DataSource = _detalleCompra.PDetalleTemp;
    }
```

Lo que necesito es saber:

1. ¿Si la implementación de crear un pk identity es correcto o hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo?.
2. ¿El DataTable me debe almacenar todos los items que ingrese, me refiero a que la fila no es nula, cuando inteto ingresar un segundo item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo, en el evento Click uso Random el cual me genera id númericos y puedo enviarselo al método agregar atravez de la propiedad `DetalleCompraId` que esta en el repositorio.
Evento Click

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rdn = new Random();
        int valor = rdn.Next();

        var entity = new DetalleCompra
        {
            DetalleCompraId = valor,
            ProductoId = Convert.ToInt32(txtProductoId.Text),
            Descripcion = txtDescripcion.Text,
            Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text),
            Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrecio.Text)
        };

        _detalleCompra.Agregar(entity);
        dgvDetalle.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvDetalle.DataSource = _detalleCompra.PDetalleTemp;
    }
```

También modifique el repositorio

```
public DetalleCompraRepository()
    {
        _detalleTemp = new DataTable("_detalleTemp");
        DataColumn colId = _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("ID", typeof (int));
        _detalleTemp.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { _detalleTemp.Columns[0] };
        _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("ProductoId", typeof(int));
        _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("Descripcion", typeof(string));
        _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("Cantidad", typeof(int));
        _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("Precio", typeof(decimal));
        _detalleTemp.Columns.Add("Importe", typeof(decimal), "(Precio * Cantidad)");
    }

public void Agregar(DetalleCompra entity)
    {
        var fila = _detalleTemp.Rows.Find(entity.DetalleCompraId);
        if (fila == null)
        {
            fila = _detalleTemp.NewRow();
            fila["ID"] = entity.DetalleCompraId;
            fila["ProductoId"] = entity.ProductoId;
            fila["Descripcion"] = entity.Descripcion;
            fila["Cantidad"] = entity.Cantidad;
            fila["Precio"] = entity.Precio;
            fila["Importe"] = entity.Total;
            _detalleTemp.Rows.Add((fila));
        }
    }
```